# ng-cloak directive gets removed too early

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular-js app with some controllers that shouldn't be shown initially. They flash on the screen despite my use of ng-cloak. The problem seems to be that compile gets called and removes the ng-cloak directives and class, this makes the controllers contents visible even though it shouldn't be because ng-show is false.

If I pause js execution in ng-cloak's compile method I can see the elements appear as the ng-cloak directive is removed. If I pause js execution in the controller (for example on "$scope.visible = false;") I can see the controller stays visible on the page. The controller is then invisible again as it should be sometime later in loading.

- I am loading my app.js and angular.js in the document HEAD
- I have my css in the document HEAD
- I have included the ng-cloak css rule with "!important" in my external css and inline

How can I prevent this flashing? Why doesn't ng-cloak pay respect to ng-show?

index.html:

```
<div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="RoomsController" ng-show="visible">
    <h1>This flashes, it can be seen if we set a breakpoint in the controller js, or after the ng-cloak directive's compile method in angular.js</h1>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
app.controller('RoomsController', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.visible = false;
    }
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting your code? So that you have a DIV with `ng-cloak` and inside of it another DIV which has the `ng-show` directive? :)

Comment: Not sure why that would help, since the ng-cloak gets removed early regardless. But I tried because you suggested it. No effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced your issue and the thing that worked for me was to create inner `div` and use `ng-if` directive instead of `ng-show`. I hope it helps.

```
<div data-ng-controller="RoomsController">
    <div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" data-ng-if="visible" >
        Some text
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only workaround I could get to work. Shouldn't ng-cloak handle my use case? Wondering if I need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with **ngCloak** in IE mobile. The simplest solution I came up with is similar to some of the other answers, but I use **ng-show** instead, and without any extra `$scope` variables:

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="true">
  {{mydata}}
</div>
```

The solution requires that you add the `ng-hide` class and `ng-show="true"`. This ensures that the element will only be visible after the `ng-show` directive is linked.

Comment: I'd say this is a better solution than the accepted answer. Easy fix and won't break any ng-show/hide animations that are already there.

Comment: What is "ng-hide" class? is it just a place holder or is there css selector ng-hide?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The only correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot messing around I managed to "fix" this by adding `ng-hide` class to the element, while removing `ng-cloak` completely:

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-controller="RoomsController" ng-show="visible">
    <h1>This flashes, it can be seen if we set a breakpoint in the controller js, or after the ng-cloak directive's compile method in angular.js</h1>
</div>
```

This hides the element initially. Angular then removes the `ng-hide` class when processing the `ng-show` directive.

Answer (score 1):

`ngCloak` directive hides the related elements until the end `compile` process. This is useful for hiding `{{ someBinding }}` stuff, and probably nothing else. The actual linking and binding in the `linking` process.

To prevent flashing of an element, it shouldn't be there until the application bootstraps itself. You can take a look at `ngInclude` for simple widgets, and `ngView` for bigger, complex things.

Comment: I tried ngInclude, but this has made the flashing even worse! The panels now animate out when they flash on the screen. I am using 1.2.0rc3 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

use a ng-hide in the class, JS will take it off or set it again even if its there but till JS kicks  in it can sit there and use CSS to hide your div

```
<div data-ng-controller="RoomsController">
    <div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak ng-hide" data-ng-if="visible" >
        Some text
    </div>        
</div>
```